# Facing issue in printing 1.004801E7 value in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to create a bill where I need to give the bill for the amount the user deposited. I'm using FreeMarker to display it. But in one case where the amount 10048010 is
is coming as like this from api 1.004801E7. Is there any issue in FreeMarker with this 1.004801E7. I'm confused whether I need to fix from API side or FreeMarker side. It will be helpful for me, if there anyway we can fix it from FTL side.

Comment: What is the type you are printing? How do you print it? Why do you think it's an issue with FreeMarker? You probably need to use https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_string_for_number

Comment: @JasperdeVries I'm printing object which is like this  {
            "payment_reciept_no": "RECEIPTPAYIP22-23-2243",
            "Mode": "Credit Card",
            "Paid_Amount": 1.004801E7,
            "Transaction_Number": "122"
          }

Comment: In your above comment that looks like JSON, which is not yet a Java object. How is the JSON passed to FreeMarker? Like will it be a `Map`? What's the type of `Paid_Amount` in what's passed to FreeMarker?

Answer (score 1):

You should format the number in the freemarker template.

There are several ways to do it.

You can either specify the number format at the top of the template, which will apply to all numbers:

```
<#setting number_format=",##0">
<#setting locale="en_US">

<#assign x = '{ "Paid_Amount": 1.004801E7 }'?eval_json >
${x.Paid_Amount}
```

This will output: `10,048,010`

or specify the format for each number individually:

```
<#setting locale="en_US">

<#assign x = '{ "Paid_Amount": 1.004801E7 }'?eval_json >
${x.Paid_Amount?string[",##0"]}
```

This will also output: `10,048,010`

The number format String uses the [Java decimal number format syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)